# How does the directed camera choose what to show?

Tags: dota-2

How does the directed camera working in Dota 2?

Particularly, how does it choose what to show to the spectators?

Comment: Nobody but the developers can know for sure, but it may look at where someone is taking damage, dying, or just point you to aggregations of heroes.

Comment: I think it's mostly unknown. But I think it's some sort of AI like the "Director" that was used in Left 4 Dead, that governs what is "important".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The directed camera is a massively complicated piece of software just in and of itself. It looks for damage taken by heroes, spells that are cast, item activations, threat determination that seems to tie into how its AI would play out a scenario, nearness to action, what happens in the next 5 seconds, and probably even where players are currently looking.

You won't find any real details anywhere, though.