# How to work with assisted directed camera?

Tags: dota-2

I've been watching a lot of tournament games lately, and I'm especially impressed with the camera work by Weppas. I heard somewhere that you can use the built in function of directed camera to broadcast, but you can choose which hero to focus on. I'm wondering if anyone has any tips for using this, and enabling it in game, since there isn't much documentation around about directed camera.

Comment: related: [How does the directed camera choose what to show?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/122487/93824)

Comment: If you change the camera mode from "directed camera" to "hero chase" it'll automatically follow that hero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The directed camera is a massively complicated piece of software just
>   in and of itself. It looks for damage taken by heroes, spells that are
>   cast, item activations, threat determination that seems to tie into
>   how its AI would play out a scenario, nearness to action, what happens
>   in the next 5 seconds, and probably even where players are currently
>   looking.
>
> You won't find any real details anywhere, though."

This answer from [decency](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/11047/decency) to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122487/how-does-the-directed-camera-choose-what-to-show?lq=1) like yours.